# Ember 2.0 handlebars helper is not a function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-2

Have been looking for a few hours a fix for this without any solution. I am trying to create a custom Ember handlebar helper using:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlight', function(value, options) {
    var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(value);
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="highlight">' + escaped + '</span>');
});
```

But for some reason I get `Uncaught TypeError: Ember.Handlebars.helper is not a function`

I read that in Ember 2 they have a new approach:

```
// app/helpers/full-name.js
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params, hash) {
  return params.join(' ');
});
```

But this is if you are using ember-cli, how about to register helper without ember-cli?

Comment: are you using ember 2.0 ?

Comment: yes, I updated title from 2 to 2.0 to make it more clearer

Comment: Great, why don't you use ember-cli? it's the recommended way to do things?

Comment: I am a bit lost as I understand ember-cli needs its own server? I am currently running ember on the zend framework2. Or is it easy to integrate into current setup?

Comment: ember-cli gives you a development server, you don't need to use it, but it helps. I suggest you read a little about ember-cli and use it? It includes as ES6 support and much more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2 they removed all Ember.Handlebars interface calls.

Use the new helper:

```
Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {

});
```

or extend the Ember.Helper

```
Ember.Helper.extend({
  // This service name is only an example
  compute(params, hash) {
    return this.get('nameBuilder').build(params, hash.title);
  },
  rebuildName: Ember.observer('nameBuilder.isAnonymized', function() {
    this.recompute();
  })
});
```

Ideally you should also use ember-cli, it's easier, as i'm not sure how you compile and get everything running without it (it's a really good build system and you can make it work with any backend service you want using

```
ember serve --proxy
```

Ember Cli

Comment: Thanks Dory for you help. I will start moving to ember-cli